# Hover Control Over Form visual studio

Tags: vb.net, combobox, controls

I am using visual studio vb.net.

Is there anyway to have a control hover over a form in the same way that when you click the dropdown arrow on a combobox the entries hover any control that are under the combobox. I have tried looking at tooltips but from what I can tell they only work with text not controls.

What I am trying to do is create some form of double combobox where I am using a datagridview as the dropdown.

I have also looked at menustips items but these seem to stop you from typing when visible.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: These are toplevel windows, there are not a lot of choices in the toolbox for such kind of window.  You'll need to create a Form class to emulate the dropdown.  And subscribe the parent form's LocationChanged event to know that you need to move it so it stays "glued" to the control.  The non-trivial problem is that you have to use the Capture property  to detect the user clicking outside of the dropdown so you know when to make it disappear again.  That interferes pretty badly with clicks on the DGV.  "Don't do it" is the only good advice imo, it is nothing that ShowDialog can't do.

Answer (score 0):

Change the control's location in the event that calls for it. Also, make sure to make the control bringtofront. For instance, set the control to not visible and then have it turn visible when the event is triggered as well as its location. The location can also be dynamic such as wherever your mouse cursor is.